# what is def variable in jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

I have two codes giving me same output. one with def and one without def. what could be the difference?

```
//code1//
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('start'){
            steps{
                script{
                    tool="beta"
                }
            }        
        }
        stage('end'){
            steps{
                echo tool
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output is beta

`//code2//`
I have same code as `//code1` but at the top of the code, i have one line extra `def tool="alpha"`
and the output is same again beta

what is the use of def in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Jenkins scoping.

- If you define a variable inside curly brackets the variable is only visible there - as you'd expect.

```
if (true) {
    def varA = 1
    echo "inside `if` varA = ${varA}"
}
echo "outside `if` varA = ${varA}" // Fails with `No such property: varA`
```

- If you define a variable outside the pipeline statement it's visible everywhere inside that pipeline statement, but not in methods you can define *outside* the pipeline statement. Not terribly intuitive, but that's Jenkins for you.
- If you don't bother to define a variable then magic happens. Jenkins defines it for you and it's global in a sense that both the pipeline statement and methods outside the pipeline statement can see it. That's why there are no good static code analysis tools for Jenkins DSL.
- You can actually define global variables in a sane manner, using `@Field` decorator.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response -can u please share a short example code for this point? "If you define a variable inside curly brackets the variable is only visible there"